# Setting up passwordless authentication from one host to another

Tags: windows, unix, ssh, authorized-keys

I am trying to set up passwordless authentication from one host to another. Below is the scenario:

User A has access to Host A (Windows Server).
User B has access to Host B (Unix Server) (Not direct access. You need to login to the host under a different account then su to User B)

I would like to know if it's possible to set up passwordless authentication for Host A to connect to Host B as User B?

I have tried to get the public key from Host A and add it to the authorized_keys (.../.ssh/authorized_keys) file. I have checked permissions on authorized_keys is 600 and on .ssh is 700.

Contents of authorized_keys is as follows:

---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQCCCIEAwc4rPjPeehHYe1VmUX4/X8pZwtqBawwD56Ksfi3wlEiM
ZlbO1kH1a+eBAC51aWgYbuAiKsLCaVVtZKx0ArcfJzWvnO36VpHGYxPEMpBG/YzoxVwh5WL2DUNijJ1/
ZePAeayg/4RvBp2y9Ds1TQB29Oe3tTVeRTY3eUky4zSWEQE== UserA@HostA
01
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----

I have tried a few combinations of User@host in the file including userB@hostB but to no avail.

Could someone please advise if I'm attempting something that's perhaps not possible (could be I'm not doing it right)? Or if there is anything I'm missing?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The authorized_keys consists of fields **options, keytype, base64-encoded key** and **comment**. In your example options is not mentioned (optional and not required). Also the last part is comment which is not really used.

On **HostB** modify **~UserB/.ssh/authorized_keys** as given below ***as a single line and watch-out that you have not introduced spaces***:

`ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQCCCIEAwc4rPjPeehHYe1VmUX4/X8pZwtqBawwD56Ksfi3wlEiMZlbO1kH1+eBAC51aWgYbuAiKsLCaVVtZKx0ArcfJzWvnO36VpHGYxPEMpBG/YzoxVwh5WL2DUNijJ1/ZePAeayg/4RvBp2y9Ds1TQB29Oe3tTVeRTY3eUky4zSWEQE== UserB@HostB`

Which ssh client are you using to connect from Host A to Host B? Cygwin ssh or Putty?

1. If you are using Cygwin ssh on HostA, try running:

   `ssh UserB@HostB` or `ssh -i <yourPrivateKey> UserB@HostB`
2. If you are using Putty, you may need to import the private key into Putty key generator and save as ".ppk" file. In hostname specify `UserB@HostB` and under Connection -> SSH -> Auth -> Private key... browse to your ".ppk" file.

Comment: Congratulations on your first upvoted answer! It is well-written and clear.